# gpg - difference --encrypt-to and --recipient

Tags: encryption, gnupg

What is the difference between `--encrypt-to` and `--recipient` and what are the advantages and disadvantages of using one over the other, which one should you use for encrypting your own files and what does the following mean?

> `--encrypt-to`
>   ... The key specified by name is used only
>   when there are other recipients given by the user or by use of the
>   option recipient. ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What is the difference between `--encrypt-to` and `--recipient`?

Summary:

> With
>   an `--encrypt-to` key designated in the Options file, GPG
>   automatically encrypts messages and files to the public keys of the
>   recipients you specify with the `--recipient` option as well as your
>   own public key. The result: both you and your recipients will be able
>   to decrypt the files or messages.

Please read the GPG Manual which explains the differences:

> `--recipient name`
>
> `-r`
>
> Encrypt for user id name. If this option or `--hidden-recipient` is not
>   specified, GnuPG asks for the user-id unless `--default-recipient` is
>   given.

And

> `--encrypt-to name`
>
> Same as `--recipient` but this one is intended for use in the options
>   file and may be used with your own user-id as an "encrypt-to-self".
>   These keys are only used when there are other recipients given either
>   by use of `--recipient` or by the asked user id. No trust checking is
>   performed for these user ids and even disabled keys can be used.

Source [Using the GNU Privacy Guard: GPG Key related Options](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Key-related-Options.html#GPG-Key-related-Options)

---

#### The documentation is not very detailed/examples may be useful

Here is some more explanation and an example:

> **"Encrypt-to-Self"**
>
> When you encrypt a file or message with the `--encrypt` command, you
>   are encrypting with someone else's public key. Strangely enough, even
>   though you encrypted the file or message yourself, you won't be able
>   to decrypt that encrypted file and access the plaintext. The only
>   person who can decrypt the file is the owner of the secret key that is
>   the partner of the public key used to encrypt the file. That's the
>   nature of asymmetric, public key encryption: you encrypt with the
>   public key and decrypt with the secret key (private key). If you don't
>   keep a copy of the plaintext original file yourself (and you probably
>   shouldn't for security reasons), then you face being locked out of the
>   very files and messages that you have encrypted and sent to other
>   people. Happily, there is a solution: the `--encrypt-to` option.
>
> You can include the `--encrypt-to` option in your Options file and
>   specify your own public key. This option is often called the
>   "encrypt-to-self" option, because it tells GPG to encrypt the message
>   with your own public key as well as your recipient's public key. With
>   an `--encrypt-to` key designated in the Options file, GPG
>   automatically encrypts messages and files to the public keys of the
>   recipients you specify with the `--recipient` option as well as your
>   own public key. The result: both you and your recipients will be able
>   to decrypt the files or messages.
>
> To use the `--encrypt-to` option in your Options file, drop the
>   leading dashes ( -- ) and specify your own key's Key ID. (You can get
>   your own Key ID with the --list-keys command.) For example, Bob (whose
>   Key ID is 0x3FAD9F1E) could include the following line in his Options
>   file:
>
> ```
> encrypt-to 0x3FAD9F1E
> ```
>
> (Note that even though Bob's key includes an encryption subkey with a
>   separate Key ID, he simply uses the Key ID for his master key.)
>
> Now Bob can encrypt a file to his friend Phil, just as he normally
>   would...
>
> ```
> D:\TEMP>gpg --recipient Phil --encrypt my-file.txt
>
> D:\TEMP>
> ```
>
> ...and still turn around and decrypt the file himself.
>
> ```
> D:\TEMP>gpg --decrypt my-file.gpg
>
> You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
> user: "Bob Bone <bobbone@cowtownu.edu>"
> 2048-bit ELG-E key, ID AB53B492, created 2001-11-13 (main key ID 3FAD9F1E)
>
> Enter passphrase: My_31337_Passphrase
>
> gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit ELG-E key, ID 42F0A0A0, created 1997-04-07
>       "Philip R. Zimmermann <prz@pgp.com>"
> gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit ELG-E key, ID AB53B492, created 2001-11-13
>       "Bob Bone <bobbone@cowtownu.edu>"
>
> This is my file.
>
> I have many such files.
>
> But this is the file I'm working with now.
>
> D:\TEMP>
> ```

Source [GnuPG Commands - Examples](http://www.spywarewarrior.com/uiuc/gpg/gpg-com-4.htm#1-3)

Comment: The documentation is not very detailed. As far as I know you can also your own user-id with `--recipient` as an "encrypt-to-self". I'm not posting a question about a quotation to get the same quotation as an answer ;|. I mean what does it mean "to be used only when there are other recipients given..." That statement is not even a correct, because you can specify no recipient at all and the `name` that is specified at `--encrypt-to` will be used. That's why I have no idea what this  `--encrypt-to` documentation actually tries to convey.

Comment: Examples may be useful :). I may also be a bug, because `gpg` does not do what's documented there.

Comment: @Ini Answer updated.

Comment: I have some more questions just to be unambigous and make this complete — maybe you can incorporate the answers to those questions into your answer too:
1) So essentially specifiyng two `--recipient`s with one being your own public key is essentially the same as one `--encrypt-to` with your own public key and `--recipient` with Bob's key?
2) Does this mean it doesen't matter which one (`--encrypt-to` or `--recipient`) you use to encrypt your own file, but it makes sense to have an `encrypt-to` statement with your own pub key in `gpg.conf` — and therefore it makes sense to use `--encrypt-to`?

Comment: 3) Does this mean that one sentence of the `--encrypt-to` documentation is wrong, because you can use the `--encrypt-to` option, without having to specify a `--recipient` or type one on prompt and the file will be encrypted with the name specified at `encrypt-to` option (as mentioned in question two of the above comment)? That contraticts with the documentation text "is used only when there are other recipients given by the user or by use of the option recipient"?

Comment: I've no idea what you are asking in the last comment. It seems clear to me. Read `--encrypt-to name` again. "Same as --recipient but this one is intended for use in the options file and may be used with your own user-id as an "encrypt-to-self". These keys are only used when there are other recipients given either by use of --recipient or by the asked user id. "

Comment: Yeah but according to that documentation when you only specify `--encrypt-to`, but no `--recipient`, then the value of `--encrypt-to` should also not be used and that means we would have no valid command and that there should be an error, which is not the case in the `gpg` implementation.

Comment: {shrug} If the docs are wrong it's not my fault. I've answered as best as I can ...

Comment: @Ini So the short-short answer is encrypt-to is the *"Same as --recipient but this one is intended for use in the options file"*, and the confusion is from an (unusual?) case of documentation bloat?

Comment: Yes, it seems so